# Expected Area of Overlapping Circles in a Torus

Tags: probability, geometry

Given a torus with a tube of circumference $1$ and outer circumference $1$, what would be the expected area covered after placing $n$ circles randomly of radius $r$.

Similar question to [expected area covered by circles inside a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985102/expected-area-covered-by-circles-inside-a-square).

Comment: I doubt "a torus with a tube of circumference 1 and outer circumference 1" physically exists, and if you represent it as a square identifying the sides you have your old problem. but the "circles" are only circles in the plain . How do you define circles on a torus?

Comment: @trula, I thought the same, the idea of a torus came from trying to make circles to the leftmost side of the square be able to overlap with one to the rightmost side of the square and likewise with the top and the bottom. Perhaps a torus isn't the best way of putting it.